# Remove special characters using Pentaho - Replace in String

Tags: regex, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I wanted to remove the special characters like `! @ # $ % ^ * _ = + | \ } { [ ] : ; < > ? /` in a string field.

I used the "Replace in String" step and enabled the use RegEx. However, I do not know the right syntax that I will put in "Search" to remove all these characters from the string. If I only put one character in the "Search" it was removed from the string. How can I remove all of these??

This is the picture of how I did it:
[image: This is the picture of how I did it]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Regex+Evaluation), the regex flavor is Java. You may use

```
\p{Punct}
```

See the [Java regex syntax reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\p{Punct}`   Punctuation: One of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

Comment: Thank you! Such a big help :)